# Comma before "but" when there is no subject?

Tags: commas

I know we need a comma in the following: "We can not control our parents, but we can control our children."

What about this though, when the subject "we" is not repeated?

"We can not control our parents but can control our children."

or

"We can not control our parents but can our children."

Comment: Your last sentence is incorrect anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, all three of your sentences are grammatical. Let me number them:

> 1. We can not control our parents, but we can control our children.
> 2. We can not control our parents but can control our children.
> 3. We can not control our parents but can our children.

**1.** This is a compound sentence. Two independent clauses, each with a subject and predicate, are joined with a comma and the coordinating conjunction *but*. In this type of construction, a comma is required after the conjunction.

**2.** This is a simple sentence with a compound predicate. Conjunctions can be used to join various parts of speech in a list. You are probably familiar with the rules for lists of nouns:

> a. The dog and cat run.
>
> b. The dog, cat, and guinea pig run.

When a list has two items, it never has a comma. When it has more than two items, commas are required (though some people omit the [final comma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_comma)). The same rules apply for verbs.

> a. The dog runs and jumps.
>
> b. The dog runs, jumps, and swims.

Your second sentence is just like example a. Though you predicates "can not control our parents" and "can control our children" are more than one word, they can still be joined with a coordinating conjunction, sans comma since there are only two of them.

**3.** This is an example of [ellipsis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis_(linguistics)): the sentence reads identically to **2**, but since the second instance of *control* is repetitive, it is omitted. The sentence remains unambiguous, and the grammatical structure is identical.